# High charts not displaying proper data timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart using high charts , however i am not able to get the readings displayed at the correct time interval .
[image]

as you can see that the chart is showing a result at 1AM however you can see that there is no 1am in my database corresponding to my result value 25 in the figure below 
[image]

my database structure
[image]

High chart php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <title>FlatWEB - Free Responsive Website HTML5 Template</title>
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://google-analytics.com/">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-ipad.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-retina.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-retina.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,400,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/resetadmin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylesgraph.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/font-awesomeadmin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,dl,input,textarea { font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; }  
  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="date.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var options;
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
        init();

   });  

   function init() {
        $('#back_btn').hide();
        options = {
          chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],

                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 20,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
                    }
                }

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {

                                $('#dateDisplay').text(this.category);

                                $.getJSON("datasoil.php?dateParam="+this.category, function(json){

                                    options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
                                    options.series[0].name = json['name'];
                                    options.series[0].data = json['data'];

                                    options.xAxis.labels = {
                                        formatter: function() {
                                        //return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value +' UTC'));
                                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value));
                                        //return this.value;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    options = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

                                    $('#back_btn').show();

                                });


                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
           }]
        }

        $.getJSON("datasoil.php", function(json){
            options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
            options.series[0].name = json['name'];
            options.series[0].data = json['data'];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    }


    function goback() {
        init();
        $('#dateDisplay').text("2013-02");
    }


    </script>
    <!--[if IE]><link href="http://www.3818.com.ar/styles/fix-old-ie.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #ads-sidebar{
            margin-right:15px!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <style>.chromeFrameInstallDefaultStyle { width: 100%; border: 5px solid #ffa700; }</style><div id="prompt"></div>
    <script>window.attachEvent("onload", function() {CFInstall.check({mode: "overlay", node: "prompt"});});</script>
<![endif]-->


<a class="scroll-point" id="home"></a>

<div id="top">
    <nav>
        <div class="logo clearfix"><a href="/ags/final/index.html#home"></a></div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="first"><a href="/ags/final/index.html#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ags/final/index.html#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ags/final/index.html#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ags/final/index.html#freebies">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="menu-dropdown hidden">
            <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
                <option value="/ags/final/index.html#home">Home</option>
                <option value="/ags/final/index.html#about">About</option>
                <option value="/ags/final/index.html#contact">Contact US</option>
                <option value="/ags/final/index.html#freebies">Login</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <a href="#menu-footer" class="menu-btn"></a>
    </nav>
</div>  
<div id="top">
</div>  
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <hgroup>
                <h1>Soil Sensor Readings</h1>

            </hgroup>       

</header>
<a class="scroll-point" id="about"></a>

<div  class="sectiongrey">

</div>

<a class="scroll-point" id="freebies"></a>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="sectionteal">

</div>


<a class="scroll-point" id="contact"></a>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="sectionorange">
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script

<section>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href=""class="button">Refresh</a>
<a href=""class="button">Back</a>
</br>
</br>
</section>

</div>
<div class="sectionblue">
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left-content">
            <a id="menu-footer"></a>
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" width="136" height="36"></div>
            <nav class="menu-footer">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#freebies">Freebies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

      </div>
        <div class="right-content">
            <div class="social">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/egrappler" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="icon-twitter"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/EGrappler" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="icon-facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/102572598506883739879" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="icon-google-plus"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://github.com/mshahbazsaleem" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="icon-github"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>


    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/themes/piha/js/top-bar.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/themes/piha/js/bsa-ads.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Dynamically creates analytics markup-->


</body>

</html>
```

High chart  database  connectivity code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_select_db("demo", $con);


if (isset($_GET["dateParam"])) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT time, value FROM soil WHERE time LIKE '".$_GET["dateParam"]."%'");
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') as time, AVG(value) as value FROM soil  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d')");
}
$result['name'] = 'Foot Traffic Count';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $datetime = $r['time'];
    $result['category'][] = $datetime;
    $result['data'][] = $r['value'];
}

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Can some one pls tell me what is  the reason for the chart not displaying the data at the correct time and what is the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Your browser shows the chart time in the time zone that is local to the user whereas your data is considered to be GMT/UTC.  You are at GMT - 6 hours which is why the time in the chart is off by 6 hours.

This is probably happening because of one of the way too many *.js files that get loaded on your page.  Get rid of all that stuff, put your chart into a simple page with nothing but jQuery and Highcharts, and try again.  It will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts uses a timestamps (time in miliseconds) so you need to transform you dates (like 2014-07-03) to timestamp. To achieve that you can use php function or use javascript.